# Dwarf offsets and shared objects vs executables

Tags: backtrace, dwarf

OK, I've used the Linux Dwarf **ldw** library to convert **backtrace_symbols** output to source code and line numbers but I've hit a snag. **backtrace_symbols** gives offsets in memory from which I subtract the base address (obtained using **dladdr()**) before using as input into Dwarf.  But it seems that for the parent executable, I should NOT subtract the base address because the Dwarf offsets seem to include it.

So how do I either distinguish between EXE and SO in my code (I'm hoping there's something better than 'look for ending .so') or is there a different function I can call that will obtain the base address or zero for the parent EXE?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right. If the executable is a `ET_EXEC` (not a `DT_DYN` i.e. it is not a position-independant executable), then the virtual addresses in the DWARF are the real virtual addresses in your program image. For `DT_DYN` the addresses in the DWARF are offsets from the base address of the module.

This is explained in [7.3](http://dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF4.pdf#page=154) of the DWARF spec:

> The relocated addresses in the debugging informations **for an executable
>   object are virtual addresses** and the relocated addresses in the
>   debugging informations **for a shared object are offsets** relative
>   to the start of the lowest region of memory loaded from that
>   shared memory.

You should use `e_type` in the ELF header to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2):

No sure if this is the best way, but **ldw** has a function, **dwarf_getelf()**, that can get you to the ELF information, from there use **elf32/64_getehdr()** and from there look at the **e_type** field.  If **e_type** is **ET_DYN** then it's a shared object and you should carry on and use **dladdr** to find the offset to delete from addresses else just use the addresses generated by **backtrace** directly.